# Issue with displaying the camera stream in an inline video tag on IOS

Tags: .net, webview, html5-video, maui-blazor

I am creating a .net maui application blazor hosted.
This app uses RecordRTC.js to access the camera.
I am able to record the camera with that.
The only issue is I can not display the camera in a video tag inline.
When I assign the stream to SrcObject, IOS pops up the video tag in fullscreen mode.
If I close the fullscreen the video stops.
I tried different video tag's attributes like muted, controls, autoplay, playsinline, webkit-playsinline and etc.
None of them works.
I've seen developers talk about allowsInlineMediaPlayback flag that helps in this situation in xamarin but I don't know how to set this flag in blazor maui.

could anyone help please?

Answer (score 0):

This is almost certainly an issue with Apple security policies / WebRTC support rather than anything at all to do with Blazor.  If there IS a solution, it will be specific to Javascript, or to the specific OS or browser, and not to Blazor.

I've been struggling for YEARS trying to get various types of media working properly on Apple products, with varying degrees of success.  But actually gaining access to hardware, for example in order to record audio or video-- that's the Holy Grail.

Apple is much more in compliance now than ever before, so I expect these problems to be mainly gone this or next year, but understand this is a browser issue, not a Blazor one.

Comment: Thanks for the response, the thing is I can record the video just fine the problem is when I want to display the camera, I can even display the camera in video tag 'but' it opens the video tag in Fullscreen mode if it is  Apple security policies issue why everything is working, my guess is it is a blazor web view configuration issue, you can even try a WebRTC demo on the web on Safari works fine, you can try this https://addpipe.com/media-recorder-api-demo/ link as well